# Wait for bool to change

Tags: vala, meson-build

The core of the issue is waiting for a condition without stopping that condition from happening. Just adding a while loop at the "Need to wait here for done to be true" comment stops anything from ever happening.

Here is a minimal reproduction of the issue (run with `vala minimal.vala --pkg gtk+-3.0`)

```
private bool done = false;


private void test () {
    GLib.Timeout.add(1000, () => {
        done = true;
        print("\ndone\n");
        Gtk.main_quit ();
        return false;
    });

    return;
}

public void main () {
    test ();
    //  Need to wait here for done to be true
    print(done.to_string ());
    Gtk.main ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The depends a bit on how your application works. Are you using the GLib main loop? What should happen when the listing is complete?

The callback includes an `eol` parameter. You could just add any action that should happen after the listing is complete to the callback when the `eol` parameter is true.

The main application should be processing messages as usually by running its main loop.

Basically you don't actually have to wait for the list to be complete. The callback will notify you when it is done.

Comment: So I have function A that needs to return a list. It then calls function B which is a void but updates the list. The issue is function B calls get_sink_info_list which uses a callback, so the function finishes before the callback. I'm not entirely sure what you mean about the eol parameter, as it's an int and in a void function so I can't return anything based on its value. This is all being called from a Gtk.Window construct

Comment: int is often used for bool in C, you should check what the value of the eol parameter is for the last invocation of the callback. (I.e. it could be a non zero value for the last invocation)

Comment: One way to implement A is to store all its state to member data and just return from A normally. When B is complete use the stored state to pick up where you left of with A. If you still don't know what I am taking about, please provide us with a more complete example.

Comment: I've just added an example of the issue. you're right that eol is 1 when it's the last result but I still don't know how to wait for that without blocking

Comment: made a super simple example of the issue, would love if you could give some pointers

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it (depends on how I got the problem):

```
// Variable is changed somewhere else
public bool variable_to_watch { get; set; } = false;

// Function to test the variable
private void test () {
    GLib.Timeout.add(1000, () => {
        if (variable_to_watch) {
            /// It's done! Call a function or trigger a signal here.
        }
        return !variable_to_watch ;
    });
}

public void main () {
    test ();
    Gtk.main ();
}
```

The other way is to use a thread:

```
// Variable is changed somewhere else
public bool variable_to_watch { get; set; } = false;

int test () {
    while (!variable_to_watch) {
        Thread.yield ();
        Thread.usleep (3600); // How frequently you want to check it?
    }
    // Call a function or signal here
    return 0;
}

public void main () {
    new Thread<int> ("test", test);
    Gtk.main ();
}
```